# Does the Java JLS specify promotion of primitive wrapper types?

Tags: java, jls

I am somewhat mystified by the output of this program:

```
public class xx {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Number x = false ? new Long(123) : new Integer(456);
        System.out.println(x + " isa " + x.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Here's what it outputs:

```
456 isa java.lang.Long
```

It appears the compiler is "promoting" an object of type `Integer` to `Long`, just as it would normally promote primitive values. I've never heard of *object promotion* and this behavior seems very surprising.

My question: is this really correct behavior according to the JLS? If so I'd like to see a reference if possible.

Or is this some kindof autoboxing-gone-wild compiler bug?

I'm using:

```
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually *binary numeric promotion* ([JLS, Section 5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)).

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>    - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.
>
> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands of certain operators:
>
> ...
>
> - In certain cases, the conditional operator ? : (§15.25)

So, the operands are unboxed and the `456` gets widened to `456L`.

Also, the specific case of `Long` and `Integer` is covered explicitly by the JLS Section for the conditional operator, [JLS Section 15.25, Table 15.25-C](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25-400-C).

> bnp(Long,Integer)

where "bnp" means binary numeric promotion.  Therefore, the conditional operator expression is of type `long`, which gets boxed to a `Long` to be assigned to a `Number`.

Answer (score 3):

The JLS defines the type of the expression `a ? b : c` in case `b` and `c` are Long and Integer respectively, in [this table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25-400-C).

The type of the expression is indeed Long, and there is indeed a binary numeric promotion (bnp) of Integer to Long.

The rule is further detailed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2):

> The type of a numeric conditional expression is determined as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.